# How to check for Cannot read property 'testUndefined' of undefined in

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I tried code follow:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-content',
  template: '
    <div *ngIf="sv.name.notExist.testUndefined != undefined">
    {{sv.name.notExist.testUndefined}}
    ',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

The variable sv.name.notExist.testUndefined is undefined, but i check it with *ngIf and the result is error with message: 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'testUndefined' of undefined in [sv.name.notExist.testUndefined != undefined in ..."

Please help me check variable undefined with *ngIf.

Comment: Quick note, what is undefined in your code is sv.name.notExist not sv.name.notExist.testUndefined, you would not get any errors if it was the latter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you should use the elvis operator

```
<div *ngIf="sv?.name?.notExist?.testUndefined">
```

This link could give you more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html. See the section "The Elvis Operator ( ?. ) and null property paths".

Hope it helps you,
Thierry